Problems adding column to Superset User model (ab_user, Flask, Flask-Migrate)
I am trying to extend the user model in Apache/Superset and add that change to the migration folder. I want to add a new column called "solution_uuid" to the model.

I made my own fork of Apache/Superset from the TAG 4.0.2 (since that was the last stable release)
Then I added my custom models.py, security.py and views.py in superset/custom directory

This is the custom user model:
from flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models import User
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    String
)
class CustomUser(User):
    __tablename__ = "ab_user"
    solution_uuid = Column(String)

Before changing the default user model to use my custom one, I ran  superset db migrate and superset db upgrade because there were some changes that hadn't been migrated apparently (I assume these are changes that were already in the source code but for some reason hadn't been migrated?). After this migration I applied my code changes and ran the same command (So now I generated 2 new migration files, the last one containing my solution_uuid changes).
When running this in docker locally it seemed to work, so I pushed the changes to my fork. The problem comes when I clone this repository into a server and try to run it (again, using docker-compose) I get the following error when superset-init runs superset db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 87d38ad83218 -> 17fcea065655, change_text_to_mediumtext
superset_init         | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 17fcea065655 -> 346d233b7fc2, empty message
superset_init         | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 346d233b7fc2 -> ddb1e557dd93, add solution_uuid
superset_db           | 2024-07-18 12:23:57.521 UTC [78] ERROR:  column "solution_uuid" of relation "ab_user" already exists
superset_db           | 2024-07-18 12:23:57.521 UTC [78] STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ab_user ADD COLUMN solution_uuid VARCHAR

It complains that the solution_uuid already exists even tho this is a new database and no other migration file adds that column.
This is the migration file with the changes I didn't make:
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
"""empty message

Revision ID: 346d233b7fc2
Revises: 17fcea065655
Create Date: 2024-07-17 10:58:57.600872

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '346d233b7fc2'
down_revision = '17fcea065655'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('annotation', 'layer_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('dashboard_roles', 'dashboard_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('dbs', 'allow_file_upload',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True,
               existing_server_default=sa.text('true'))
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, 'dynamic_plugin', ['bundle_url'])
    op.alter_column('embedded_dashboards', 'uuid',
               existing_type=postgresql.UUID(),
               nullable=False)
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'embedded_dashboards', 'ab_user', ['changed_by_fk'], ['id'])
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'embedded_dashboards', 'ab_user', ['created_by_fk'], ['id'])
    op.drop_index('ix_key_value_expires_on', table_name='key_value')
    op.drop_index('ix_key_value_uuid', table_name='key_value')
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, 'key_value', ['uuid'])
    op.drop_index('ix_logs_user_id_dttm', table_name='logs')
    op.alter_column('report_schedule', 'extra_json',
               existing_type=sa.TEXT(),
               nullable=True)
    op.drop_index('ix_creation_method', table_name='report_schedule')
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, 'report_schedule_user', ['user_id', 'report_schedule_id'])
    op.drop_index('ix_row_level_security_filters_filter_type', table_name='row_level_security_filters')
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_additive',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_aggregation',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_increase_desired',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_partition',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_physical',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_spatial',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_temporal',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.drop_constraint('sl_table_columns_column_id_fkey', 'sl_table_columns', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint('sl_table_columns_table_id_fkey', 'sl_table_columns', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'sl_table_columns', 'sl_columns', ['column_id'], ['id'], ondelete='CASCADE')
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'sl_table_columns', 'sl_tables', ['table_id'], ['id'], ondelete='CASCADE')
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, 'sl_tables', ['database_id', 'catalog', 'schema', 'name'])
    op.alter_column('ssh_tunnels', 'database_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=False)
    op.drop_index('ix_ssh_tunnels_database_id', table_name='ssh_tunnels')
    op.drop_index('ix_ssh_tunnels_uuid', table_name='ssh_tunnels')
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, 'ssh_tunnels', ['uuid'])
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, 'ssh_tunnels', ['database_id'])
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'ssh_tunnels', 'ab_user', ['created_by_fk'], ['id'])
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'ssh_tunnels', 'ab_user', ['changed_by_fk'], ['id'])
    op.alter_column('tab_state', 'autorun',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('tab_state', 'hide_left_bar',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=True,
               existing_server_default=sa.text('false'))
    op.drop_index('ix_tab_state_id', table_name='tab_state')
    op.drop_index('ix_table_schema_id', table_name='table_schema')
    op.drop_index('ix_tagged_object_object_id', table_name='tagged_object')
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'tagged_object', 'slices', ['object_id'], ['id'])
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'tagged_object', 'dashboards', ['object_id'], ['id'])
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'tagged_object', 'saved_query', ['object_id'], ['id'])
    op.alter_column('user_favorite_tag', 'user_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('user_favorite_tag', 'tag_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('user_favorite_tag', 'tag_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('user_favorite_tag', 'user_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=False)
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'tagged_object', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'tagged_object', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'tagged_object', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_index('ix_tagged_object_object_id', 'tagged_object', ['object_id'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_table_schema_id', 'table_schema', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_tab_state_id', 'tab_state', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.alter_column('tab_state', 'hide_left_bar',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False,
               existing_server_default=sa.text('false'))
    op.alter_column('tab_state', 'autorun',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'ssh_tunnels', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'ssh_tunnels', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'ssh_tunnels', type_='unique')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'ssh_tunnels', type_='unique')
    op.create_index('ix_ssh_tunnels_uuid', 'ssh_tunnels', ['uuid'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_ssh_tunnels_database_id', 'ssh_tunnels', ['database_id'], unique=False)
    op.alter_column('ssh_tunnels', 'database_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=True)
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'sl_tables', type_='unique')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'sl_table_columns', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'sl_table_columns', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_foreign_key('sl_table_columns_table_id_fkey', 'sl_table_columns', 'sl_tables', ['table_id'], ['id'])
    op.create_foreign_key('sl_table_columns_column_id_fkey', 'sl_table_columns', 'sl_columns', ['column_id'], ['id'])
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_temporal',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_spatial',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_physical',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_partition',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_increase_desired',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_aggregation',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.alter_column('sl_columns', 'is_additive',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False)
    op.create_index('ix_row_level_security_filters_filter_type', 'row_level_security_filters', ['filter_type'], unique=False)
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'report_schedule_user', type_='unique')
    op.create_index('ix_creation_method', 'report_schedule', ['creation_method'], unique=False)
    op.alter_column('report_schedule', 'extra_json',
               existing_type=sa.TEXT(),
               nullable=False)
    op.create_index('ix_logs_user_id_dttm', 'logs', ['user_id', 'dttm'], unique=False)
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'key_value', type_='unique')
    op.create_index('ix_key_value_uuid', 'key_value', ['uuid'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_key_value_expires_on', 'key_value', ['expires_on'], unique=False)
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'embedded_dashboards', type_='foreignkey')
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'embedded_dashboards', type_='foreignkey')
    op.alter_column('embedded_dashboards', 'uuid',
               existing_type=postgresql.UUID(),
               nullable=True)
    op.drop_constraint(None, 'dynamic_plugin', type_='unique')
    op.alter_column('dbs', 'allow_file_upload',
               existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
               nullable=False,
               existing_server_default=sa.text('true'))
    op.alter_column('dashboard_roles', 'dashboard_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=True)
    op.alter_column('annotation', 'layer_id',
               existing_type=sa.INTEGER(),
               nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###

And this is the one with my changes
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
"""add solution_uuid

Revision ID: ddb1e557dd93
Revises: 346d233b7fc2
Create Date: 2024-07-17 11:18:33.257574

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'ddb1e557dd93'
down_revision = '346d233b7fc2'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('ab_user', sa.Column('solution_uuid', sa.String(), nullable=True))
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_column('ab_user', 'solution_uuid')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


Any idea why this is happening?

I managed to make it work in the server by doing the same as locally. I pulled the code at the same tag 4.0.2, then started the docker-compose container, then made all my changes, ran superset db upgrade, and it worked.
This still isn't a proper solution and I would really like to understand why I can't run my migration files from the start... it makes no sense to have to first launch everything and then upgrade again. Any help would be appreciated
